# Replace a substring that is between square brackets with php regex

Tags: php, regex

Here is the substring I am working with

```
[sitetree_link%20id=2]
```

I need to replace all occurrences of %20 that fall between [ ] with a blank space. But obviously if there are %20s outside of [ ] braces, leave them alone...

I'm just learning regex now but this one seems pretty tough. Anyone got a super smart regex for this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
$result = preg_replace('/(\[[^]]*?)(%20)([^]]*?\])/m', '$1 $3', $subject);
```

**Explanation**

```
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \[         # Match the character “[” literally
   [^]]       # Match any character that is NOT a “]”
      *?         # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
)
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   %20        # Match the characters “%20” literally
)
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3
   [^]]       # Match any character that is NOT a “]”
      *?         # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
   \]         # Match the character “]” literally
)
```

Comment: Aah almost! Just need to replace with an empty space ie. " " instead of ""

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Perfect, cheers for the explanation too. Have an awesome weekend!

Comment: That worked for me!! Thanks
What if the (%20) value  it occurs more than once in the string?
example [sitetree_link%20id=2&sitetree2_link%20id=3]
I test it but it revoves just the first one.
How can we tell to remove it more then once?

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier is pointless because there is not start of string (`^`) or end of string (`$`) metacharacters in the pattern.